# Where is a good tutorial to use Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, webapp-rec

The help system of Google Sheets is a bit short on detail (to put it nicely).

Are there any good tutorials / documentation to explain to a non-Excel-savvy user how the formulas work, how one should use them (examples) and so on and so forth?

Comment: This question was posted during the private beta. It's worthy to not that nowadays Google Sheets is the most popular tag here.

Answer (score 0):

By far not a complete answer, but a start -

Here is a nice tutorial for google forms:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzgaUOW6GIs

From the google youtube user:  http://www.youtube.com/user/Google

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, in the new Google Spreadsheet (bound to be a standard soon) each formula has a somewhat extended example usage, in comparison to the old Google Spreadsheet. See screenshot of the `QUERY` text:

[image]

Clicking the [hyperlink](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB), will take you to a landing page, especially for the `QUERY` function. In the case of the `QUERY` function there are multiple examples illustrated.

I find **[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)** the place to be for Google Spreadsheet Q&A. People over here will take the time to give good answers (and ask good questions !!)